# Fullcalendar v2 how on select free time on resource open appointment create blade with selected dates? Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have fullcalendar v2 and Laravel application. Almost everything is done with databases an other stuff but last thing is missing. I am not so good at JS and need someone help.

I have this script and it works good for displaying appointments and resources

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var events ={!! json_encode($events) !!};
      var resources ={!! json_encode($resources) !!};
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
        editable: true,
        height: 1150,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        views: {
            agendaTwoDay: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: { days: 2 },

                // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
                // so, we need to explicitly enable it
                groupByResource: true

                //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
                //groupByDateAndResource: true
            }
        },

        //// uncomment this line to hide the all-day slot
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        hiddenDays: [0],
        minTime:"07:00:00",
        maxTime: "23:59:59",
        slotDuration:"00:15:00",

        resources: resources,
        events: events,

        selectable: true,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        select: function(startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {
            alert('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format() + ' on resource ' + resource.id);
        }
    });
  })
```

My need here is to on selecting free time, my application opens create-appointment.blade.php and parse resource, startDatetime and endDatetime

Comment: You want to open a totally separate page, or just a popup?

Comment: You can detect a user selection with `select` as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-method (you can use v3 docs for v2 as the API is basically the same). Once you're in there, you can write some Javascript to do whatever you want. I would suggest it will be more user-friendly and easier to implement with fullcalendar, to open a HTML modal rather than redirecting to a totally separate page.

Comment: @ADyson my need is to open seperate page

Comment: So just use window.location then. You'll need to pass relevant info such as the selected dates in the querystring